# is it possible to recursively walk through object with jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

`expect(res.body.result.verificationToken).toBeDefined()`

if it's not a success response, jest will throw an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/favkU.png) that I don't want.

I wanna first check if the properties are already there.

I know, I can acquire this by `lodash` (`_.get`). But I wanna know is it possible with jest without using other libs.

Comment: The error you mentioned is not thrown by Jest but by the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: I have provided an image @EstusFlask

Comment: I see. Please, remove the image and place the error as text. All important information should be available in question body without navigating to external links, this is required by SO rules.

Answer (score 3):

The expectation you need is [`.toHaveProperty()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value):

```js
expect(res).toHaveProperty('body.result.verificationToken');
```

Alternatively you can pass the names of the properties as an array:

```js
expect(res).toHaveProperty(['body', 'result', 'verificationToken']);
```

The second format is more intuitive when arrays are involved in the path but the first format can be used as well, using numbers (the indices) as properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to avoid this error with null-coalescing (elvis) operator:

```
res.body.result?.verificationToken
```

But the assertion will still fail because the result is `undefined`.

This addresses the wrong problem. Expectations in tests should preferably be as precise as possible. If it's unknown that a response is successful, there are problems with testing conditions.

Instead, it can be:

```
// in a test where failed response is expected
expect(res.body.result).not.toBeDefined()

// in a test where success response is expected
expect(res.body.result.verificationToken).toBeDefined()
```